# express.static not serving .html file from public folder

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I am currently working on my first little Node/Express project, and I am having difficulties with the express.static function. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution for my issue amongst all the other threads about this topic on here. I have also gone through all the docs I could find. It seems that I am still not getting any further.

Here's my set up:

I have added a "/public" folder to my project dir. In "public" I have "documentation.html". The structure looks like this:

-project_folder

--public

----documentation

It is the "documentation.html" I would like to serve for the endpoint "/documentation".

By now I have tried the following:

The example from the Express docs:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

With the endpoint "/documentation" I get a status: 301, moved permanently, type: document/redirect, and initiator: other for "documentation, and a status: 404, not found and type: document and initiator: :8080/documentation, redirect for "documentation/".

---

A suggestion to add a "/" before the "public":

```
app.use(express.static('/public'));
```

With the endpoint "/documentation" I get a status: 301, moved permanently, type: document/redirect, and initiator: other for "documentation, and a status: 404, not found and type: document and initiator: :8080/documentation, redirect for "documentation/".

---

The recommended way from the Express docs (I did require path for this one):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

With the endpoint "/documentation" I get a status: 301, moved permanently, type: document/redirect, and initiator: other for "documentation, and a status: 404, not found and type: document and initiator: :8080/documentation, redirect for "documentation/".

---

The endpoint "/movies" does return a JSON object, and the endpoint "/" does return "Some text".

Another thing to mention: I had an index.html within the "public" folder before. With

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

and the endpoint "/documentation" I received the "index.html" file.

Here is the code:

```
//Requiring Express
const express = require('express');
//Setting Express to var "app"
const app = express();

let topMovies = [{ title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: 'Die Hard', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }];

//GET requests
app.get('/movies', (req, res) => {
  res.json(topMovies);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Some text')
});

//Serving static files from "public" folder using express "static" function
app.use(express.static('public'));

//Server PORT
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server running...');
});
```

As mentioned, this is my first time working with Node/Express. I am quite confident that I checked all the docs and threads with similar issues before creating this post. However, I apologize in advance if I overlooked something at this point.

**Edit/Addition:**

I have been able to run another test, which however, confuses my beginner brain even more. Here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

let topMovies = [{ name: 'test' }, { name: 'testone' }, { name: 'testtwo' }];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/movies', (req, res) => {
  res.json(topMovies);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port: ${PORT}`));
```

I used this folder structure:

project_root
index.js
public
index.html

With this code and folder structure, I can get the static files served on "localhost:3000".

What becomes clear to me is:

1. The file name of "index.html" in /public works, while "documentation.html" doesn't.
2. "/movies" still returns the JSON object
3. The folder structure is the same in both examples.
4. I simply changed the PORT # and how the PORT was "referenced" in app.listen
5. I just don't know what the f I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue is about conflict in the API call of `GET /`. There are two binding points, first, return 'Some Text', and second, return static files.

To solve you should separate these endpoints either by removing `app.get('/',...` or by adding another prefix for static files: `app.use('/ui', express.static('public'));`

To serve your documents, just rename `document.html` to `index.html` and bind the directory: `app.use('/document', express.static('document'));`

**Best Practice**

It is highly recommended to add a default prefix for all API calls.

```js
const path = require('path');

app.get('/api/movies', (req, res) => {
  res.json(topMovies);
});
app.get('/api/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Some text');
});

app.use('/document', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'document')));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

```
project-root
  public
     index.html
  document
     index.html
  index.js
  package.json
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work. When I try to run this server with "node index.js", I get "path is not defined".

Comment: I ignored the full code, I tried to show you how things get around. You need to require `path` module to fix (as I  edited).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a lot of trial an error I figured it out. Here's what worked for me:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

let topMovies = [{ title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: 'Die Hard', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }, { title: '', director: '' }];

app.get('/movies', (req, res) => {
  res.json(topMovies);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Netflix sucks');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server is running....'));
```

Folder structure:

```
-project_root

--index.js

--public

----documentation.html
```

---

Now, I get the "documentation.html" for the endpoint "/documentation.html" and also the other endpoints are returned correct.

**Conclusion**: I had the right folder structure, but I needed to add the "__dirname" to the express.static root and also make the "public" folder a path by adding "/".