# Having trouble accessing subroutes of vue app directly

Tags: vue.js, express

I'm working on a express + vue project with the following structure (see below), and I have trouble accessing subroutes of the vue app directly in production (hosted on Heroku). For instance, I can go to `www.example.com` and can access subroutes from the index page, but typing `www.example.com/subpage` directly gives the following errors.

More context: I currently manually copy the built files from `frontend/dist` to `public`. To get it to work, I am using publicPath `./` in vue.config.js. In development if I change the publicPath to `/`, I don't get the above problem.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at chunk-vendors.25f4b4fa.js:1:1)
app.c661c8f0.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at app.c661c8f0.js:1:1)
manifest.json:1 
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

Folder Structure

```
mainfolder
--> frontend (vue development files)
    ---> dist
--> src (express backend)
--> public (where I copy the built vue files)
    ---> js
    ---> css
    ---> img
    ---> index.html
```

express app.js file

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});
app.use(require('connect-history-api-fallback')());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not serving static files properly. Let Node.Js ecosystems take care of returning your UI file.

```js
// app.use(express.static('public'));
// app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
//  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
// });

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.use(require('connect-history-api-fallback')());
```

If the `index.htm` does not load its JavaScript dependencies, you need to rebuild the UI taking care of subdomains.

To serve your static files in a better way, please look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72193594/express-static-not-serving-html-file-from-public-folder/72196500#72196500).